# Manually (aapt) add native library .so to apk

Tags: android, android-ndk, aapt

For multiple reasons I'm building my project manually (more or less following these steps http://geosoft.no/development/android.html), whithout using ant.

My projects uses the NDK and builds a `.so` library.

- With Eclipse:

When I use Eclipse to build my project, everything works: I drag&drop `libMyNativeLib.so` in the `libs/armeabi` directory and when I call `loadLibrary(MyNativeLib)` it works fine: I can call native method from my Java code.

- Manually:

Now I want to build manually my `.apk`. Everything works except from the native lib loading.
Using `aapt add`, I have added in my apk : `lib/armeabi/libMyNativeLib.so` (I saw that the apk generated by Eclipse contains this .so in `lib/armeabi` so I used the same path in the apk).
When calling `loadLibrary(MyNativeLib)`, I got the following exception

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load MyNativeLib from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList...
```

Why is that ?

Should I do something in the `dx --dex` step regarding the native code (`.so` lib) ? I don't think so but I'm maybe wrong ? (I'm only using `dx --dex` with my `.jar` libs which is logic I guess).

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure why you elected to avoid Ant. Gradle, with the Gradle for Android plugin, may not have the problems you experienced with Ant, and will be a more reliable solution than manually assembling your APK IMHO.

Comment: Remove the apk and reinstall, while watching unfiltered logcat in another terminal for any relevant complaints.  Use run-as or the implicitly rooted emulator to look at the installation and see if the file exists and is unpacked, and (using `ls -l`) if it has the executable bit set.  Unzip a valid apk with a native library and compare to your non-working one.  The .so file is getting signed along with everything else, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to apktool (http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) I found out what was wrong.

The makefile that generates the final `.apk` bundle had an error. Indeed the `aapt add` command contained `\` in the path instead of `/`. As I'm generating on Windows, all my paths use `\` as a separator. That's why I used `\` for `aapt add`. However as this path is used during the installation of the `.apk` on Android (Unix), then I should have used `/` separator.

Comment: Please post the actual aapt invocation you used. I know your problem is solved, but it would be helpful to others who happen upon this answer. It's not included in the original question post either.