# How to generate a shared library temporary and pack it into a APK package

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, android-build, android-install-apk

I have a android app called "ABC" which needs to pack a jni shared library called "libxxx-jni.so". So the source tree is likes as below:

```
ABC
+- Android.mk
+- java
+- res
+- jni
    +- Android.mk
    +- xxx.cpp
```

The Android.mk of ABC app is:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := ABC
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java)

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/res

LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libxxx-jni

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

# Also build sub-targets under this one: the shared library.  
include $(call all-makefiles-under, $(LOCAL_PATH))
```

And the Android.mk of jni library xxx is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libxxx-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := xxx.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libutils \
    libcutils

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
    $(JNI_H_INCLUDE)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I put these source code in android aosp source tree, and use android build environment to build whole system.

My problem is I need to pack the libxxx-jni.so into my Settings apk. Currently, after build completed, I see the libxxx-jni.so is located at /system/lib. In APK's lib sub-folder, I only see a link to the /system/lib/libxxx-jni.c.

That's not my expectation. I want to pack the so in my APK's lib sub-folder, not just a link. And I don't want to the libxxx-jni.so is appeared in /system/lib.

I didn't use IDE (eclipse or android studio), and I only use Android.mk in aosp source tree.

How should I modify these Android.mk to meet my expectation? Thanks.

Comment: AOSP build does really work as you describe: the app you build is considered a *system app*, and all native libs it depends on, are installed to `/system/lib`. This makes sense, because this app will never be *installed*, and the *pm* will not have a chance the extract the packed native libs, the way it happens to regular APKs.

Comment: You can add any file to your APK with the help of `aapt` command, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23655436/192373.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Android.mk:

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := samples

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to achieve bundling of JNI .so's in the apk when using AOSP, basically all [listed in the build system](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/master/core/install_jni_libs.mk):

- a) make TARGET_BUILD_APPS become true: one way to do this is by building your app via tapas instead of lunch: `. build/envsetup.sh; lunch <yourlunchtarget>; m <yourapp>` becomes `. build/envsetup.sh; tapas <yourapp> [arm|x86|arm64|x86_64] [eng|userdebug|user]; make`.
- b) set [`LOCAL_COMPRESSED_MODULE`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/7c20510%5E%21/) to true.
- c) set `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS` to `samples` or `tests` as [noted by huisinro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69375182/361413). Not sure about the side effects and if your app is not a sample or a test this feels semantically wrong.